# PDO::PARAM_INT behaviour in PHP 7.1 & PHP 7.2

Tags: php, pdo, php-7.2

When passing a string with PDO::PARAM_INT there seems to be a change of behaviour in PHP 7.2. In Version 7.1 the updated value and the passed string were identical, in PHP 7.2 the updated value is "3" (see example below).

Of course I'm aware that passing a string using PDO::PARAM_INT is wrong, but I'm wondering why there is nothing to be found in the PHP changelog and why there is no exception or warning thrown.

Does anyone know if this is a desired behaviour?

```
$sql = "UPDATE test SET name = :name WHERE id = 1";

$update = $db->prepare($sql);   
$update->bindValue(':name', '3hgsf5-458752shUGVZCF', PDO::PARAM_INT);

$update->execute();
```

Comment: It could be a (mysql) driver issue, as a quick test with SQLite in PHP 7.1 yielded the expected string "3" for me.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll try to check it out.

Comment: It would help to know which database and database driver versions you use. A quick test in PHP 5 yielded that MySQL uses the full string while SQLite uses the number.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB Version 10.2.21

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a side-effect of fixing https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73234

https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/32b6154a61fae820386527f3019f8c5937fc5d27