# whereIn Laravel 5.8 issue

Tags: php, laravel

My query with **whereIn** only works with **string array** and **integer array** containing number < 10 ( example `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` will work ).

This will return an empty collection.

```
$sql = DB::table('simple_table');
$sql->whereIn('question_id', [10, 12);
```

And this will return the expected result.

```
// string array | work
$sql = DB::table('simple_table');
$sql->whereIn('question_id', ['10', '12']);

// integer array containing number < 10 | work
$sql = DB::table('simple_table');
$sql->whereIn('question_id', [1, 2]);
```

`question_id` field is string type.

With Laravel 5.2 and **whereIn** will work for both string and integer.

Any known issues or changes with **whereIn** in Laravel 5.8??

**UPDATED**

```
// work
DB::select('select * from outbound_questions where question_alias IN (10, 12)')
// not work
DB::select('select * from outbound_questions where question_alias IN (?)', [10])
```

I updated Laravel to 6.x and PHP 7.3, the issue still there...

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @sta Sorry you, my english is bad. My question is "Any known issues or changes with whereIn in Laravel 5.8??"

Comment: I doubled check on my local, it work just fine. There are no chances on whereIn clause.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi Laravel 5.2 it's work fine. Still don't know why I have this issue. I'm trying to test another version. Thank you.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi I updated Laravel to 6.x and PHP 7.3 and the issue still there...

Comment: I have no idea about this mystical issue

Comment: @AhmadKarimi Seem like the issue comes from PHP version. Using Laravel 5.4, PHP 5.6.40 works fine. Maybe related to PDO issue on PHP 7. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413798/pdoparam-int-behaviour-in-php-7-1-php-7-2